# Top Border Image in CSS3

Tags: css

I've used `border`, `border-top-image`, `border-image` and none seem to do what I am after.

I have the following CSS:

```css
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 26px 0 30px 0;
    border-top-image: url('http://www.mycelticcrossstitch.com/celtic%20knot%20cross%20stitch.jpg');
    font-size: 0.8461538461538462em;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

This does not seem to apply to the website I am trying to work on, I've tried it in Firefox and Chrome.

I only want the image to appear on the top border and wish to have no other borders (so it's sort of like a `<hr />`)

Comment: You really don't need that much precision in your `font-size`.

Comment: Yes I do, it works great.

Comment: @thirtydot it is futureproof until the year 6000

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think that there is any such property like `border-top-image` to give image border to any side of an element - 
Use

```
border-image:url('http://www.mycelticcrossstitch.com/celtic%20knot%20cross%20stitch.jpg') 30 30 round;
```

but it give border around all sides. To remove border around rest of the sides I gave -

```
border-bottom:0;
border-left:0;
border-right:0;
```

It worked and here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/c7WxG/1/

Comment: It doesn't work on Firefox. I ran this on an iPad via IonicFramework & Apache Cordova and it doesn't work either. It works on Chrome though.

Answer (score 11):

There is the `border-image-width: a b c d;` property. The details:

- `a-d` are the widths of the top, right, bottom and left borders, respectively
- values of a-d may be in the form:

  - `[x]px`
  - `[x]`  - multiples of border-width value
  - `[x]%`  - percent of the image slice (appears non-working in Safari 7)
  - `auto`  - derive from the width of the corresponding image slice
- the default value is `1`.
- if you omit `d`, the value of `b` is used for the left border width
- if you also omit `c`, the value of `a` is also used for the bottom border width
- if you also omit `b`, the value of `a` is used for all borders :)

So for your example you could use:

```
border-image-width: 100% 0 0 0;
```

Alternatively the `border-image` shorthand property includes `border-image-width` as a parameter, so in one line of CSS:

```
border-image: url(image.png) 100% 0 0 0 / [desired_border_width]px 0 0 0 repeat;
```

This uses the entire image for the top slice ("100% 0 0 0") and applies it as the top border at the desired width.

Comment: border-image-width: 100% 0 0 0; the droids I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

**Another SOLUTION**  - create visual **"BEFORE"** phseudo-element :

```
.yourDiv::before{
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/200/100/");
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you wish to have no other borders, so instead of `border-image-width` you can also simply use the `border-width` shorthand :

see https://jsfiddle.net/j2x6n3q9/

Answer (score -2):

The border image is specified as a URI, for two different groups:
The URI of upto three images may be specified for each of the four border edges. If one image URI is given, the first tile is centered on the border line. If two image URIs are given, they meet at the center of the border line with the first image placed on the top or left side of the center. If three image URIs are given, the second becomes the center and does not tile. The other two are placed on either side of the center image, with the first going on the top or left side of the center and the third going on the bottom or right.

For more refer w3.org

Comment: That was a...strange... way to respond to MotaBOS's comment, Ecko. Don't do that. Post a reply in a comment, if you have the rep to do so.

Comment: I didn't reply it in any negative way. I was referring to the answer of the above question concerning the border.

Comment: I get that.  Use a comment to reply (like I have here), not your answer.